# How do I use rvest with an element id name that contains a forward slash?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to use rvest to screen scrape an an element id that contains a forward slash.  It seems that everything I try as an escape character fails.  Suppose that the element I'm trying to select is

```
<div id ="hello/world"> Some stuff </div>
```

Using rvest functions, after reading the webpage into a variable called "html", I'm running things like this:

```
x <- html %>% 
  html_elements("#hello//world")
```

I've done it using no escape character, different escape characters, etc.  But everything I try generates the error:

```
Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 8.
```

Any ideas?  Big thanks for any help.

Comment: What is it that you want to extract from the HTML? In your example `div` is the element, so I'm not sure why you're supplying the value of the "id" attribute to `html_elements()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `html_nodes` ?

```
library(rvest)

html <- read_html('<div id="hello/world"> Some stuff </div>')
html %>% 
  html_nodes("div[id='hello/world']")
```

Result:

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div id="hello/world"> Some stuff </div>
```

Comment: This worked -- big thanks!  Unfortunately, I have no idea why.  The documentation for rvest makes it clear that html_nodes has been superseded by html_elements.  Either way, I can't see why escaping would work one way in html_nodes (not necessary inside the quoted string that's passed as an argument) and differently in html_elements.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Yes, looks like there have been recent updates to rvest, I wasn't aware of them. I can only say that `html_nodes` still seems to work better for this use case :) We'd have to look at the source code to understand the escape issue.

Comment: I had success with `html_elements` but specifying the `xpath` argument explicitly, so in this case it would be `html_elements(xpath = "div[id='hello/world']")`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are searching for an  id attribute not an element. Perhaps you can try instead:

```r
x <- html %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = "//div[@id='hello/world']")
```

Comment: Yes, this does work.  Thanks!  But I don't think this is quite the recommended approach.  From the rvest documentation: "#title: selects the element with the id attribute that equals “title”. Id attributes must be unique within a document, so this will only ever select a single element."